# Attaching Google Sheet to emails from Gmail automatically using G Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I found a G Script that works for sending an email to hundreds of addresses, based on an excel file with the name (which I can convert into Sheets if necessary).

I want to be able to add an attachment (which is currently an excel file, but can easily be converted into Sheets) to each email that is sent. The attachment is the same for each email.

The below script works for sending the emails, but I can't find the right way to add an attachment to each email (Note: line 17 is where I'm getting the error code).

I've tried a few different versions based on other similar strings on this site - but I can't get it to work with my situation, or maybe I don't understand how to structure the syntax accordingly.

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
 function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B2
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1);
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
var message = row[1]; // Second column
var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet'
var file = Drive.Files.get('test123/xlsx');
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: 
  [file]});
   }
  }
```

> ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined. (line 17, file "Code")

Comment: Where did you get the code?

Comment: I found the code here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails.. the line 17 I just added in because I saw something similar to that in one of these posts on stackoverflow. I thought I could just add it in as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), it looks like the class you're looking for is DriveApp.

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
 function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B2
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('test123/xlsx');
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: 
  [file]});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jen. What would I use if I wanted to pull an excel document off my desktop rather than use Drive?

Answer (score 2):

"Drive" is the Advanced Drive API.In order to use the Drive advanced api you need to enable that api. But you really don't need the advanced api here.

Is your file in drive?

If so try this instead:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXXXXX");
```

the "xxx" should be the drive id.

Comment: This worked! Sort of. The email sent with an attachment. The correct test123 file I was looking for once I found the ID. But it came in PDF, not an editable excel or Google Sheets version (currently, in my Google Drive, its saved as Google Sheets). Any ideas on that front?

Comment: If you are using a google sheet, I would just add "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" to the message of the email, it will "attach" any native drive files.

Comment: But make sure it has been shared with them outside the email.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help J.G. When you say add to the message of the email, do you mean to add it into the cell within the sheet that I am currently referencing in the script on line 13? var message = row[1]; - or do I need to somehow attach that piece onto line 13 within the script itself? I've tried both ways unseccesfully. I'm, not sure how to bring in the actual message (row[1]) and add "drive.google.com/open?id=" to it.

Comment: var message = row[1] + "  drive.google.com/open?id=XXXXX"; should work. Alternately if you share the file with everyone from the spreadsheet interface, you can just add a message, because they will all get an email with the attachment, skipping the need for scripts altogether.

Comment: Beautiful; it works! Thanks for your help and patience.